# How to create a html table from the values of mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to create a html table which will show the values from the mysql array along with their field name for e.g. I have a table with three columns in it and I want to show it all in a table format like:

```
Name  | Age | Telephone  |
User  | 22  | 1234568098 | 
User1 | 22  | 1234568098 | 
User2 | 22  | 1234568098 | 
User3 | 22  | 1234568098 | 
User4 | 22  | 1234568098 |
```

I want to dynamically count the mysql columns and display them in a html table along with its values.

I know the PHP `count()` function and how to create a table in html.

Comment: If you want dynamically to fetch the column names and count, you need to query the db named "information_schema"

Comment: i have tried the basic while statement but i want to create a function  so that i can use it whenever and for any table. i just dont want to write down the code for every table to display its data

Comment: Then try writing your function, which will take some input variables and output the result. If you stuck somewhere, post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is the solution, I did it only because it's not that trivial (but it's not hard either). Next time post code you tried.

OK, back to question, I did it using PDO, there are other ways out there also. Also I'm echoing HTML from PHP which doesn't look nice, but for simplicity of this problem I would leave it as is.

```
$sth = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users;");
$data = $sth->fetchAll();

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<thead>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $sth->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $column = $sth->getColumnMeta($i);
    echo "<th>" . $column['name'] . "</th>";
}


echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

foreach($data as $column=>$row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";         
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```